# preview before submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

can anybody tell me how to make preview before submit in one form using javascript in php

i have an example like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() { 
    `$('#db').hide();
    });

function preview()
    {
           var add=document.getElementById('Address_Street').value;
    if(add.trim()!="")
        {       
            $('#db').show();
      document.getElementById('p_Address_Street').value=add;                
        }
    }
```

```
<body>
<form name="approval" id="approval" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<input type="text" name="Address_Street" id="Address_Street" size="36" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >`
<input type="button" value="Preview" onclick="preview()">
</form>
<div id="db">
  Address Street: <input type="text" name="p_Address_Street" id="p_Address_Street" size="36" value="" readonly="readonly">
</div>
</body>
```

can everybody tell me the right one please :(

Comment: preview means what exactly you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272275/display-user-entered-data-in-the-form-before-submitting-to-database

Answer (score 2):

Add id to your Preview button

```
<input id="Preview" type="button" value="Preview">
```

Then try this Js

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#db').hide();
    $('#Preview').on('click', function(){
        var add=$("#Address_Street").val();
        if(add.trim()!="")
        {       
            $('#db').show();
            $('#p_Address_Street').val(add);               
        }    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error on this line
`` `$('#db').hide(); `` try to remove the ` char

And then, if you're using JQuery, stick to it.

`var add = $('#Address_Street').val();`

To debug, remove the if statement. Maybe the error is there.

The example:
http://jsfiddle.net/fa295/

Comment: can you give an example?